# How to populate 2D array from the file

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a file with one parameter per line:

```
a1
b1
c1
a2
b2
c2
...
```

The parameters are lines of characters (not numbers)

I need to load it to 2D array for further manipulations.
So far I managed to upload this file into 1D array:

```
ParametersRaw = []
with open(file1) as fh:
    ParametersRaw = fh.readlines()
fh.close()

NumberOfColumns = 7
NumberOfRows = len(ParametersRaw)/NumberOfColumns

Parameters = [[],[]]
i=0
j=0
k=0
while (i < NumberOfRows):
    while (j < NumberOfColumns):
        k = (i*NumberOfColumns)+j
        Parameters[i][j] = ParametersRaw[k]
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
    j = 0
```

it fails at the line `Parameters[i][j] = ParametersRaw[k]` with error:

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

In case of populating 1D array I would use append() method.
But in case of 2D I am lost of how append() can be applied.

Leonid

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provide a sample of a resulting 2D array you want to get

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question, but if you start with

```
parameters = [[''], ['']]
```

then

```
parameters[0][0]
```

is `''`

What you have, `Parameters = [[],[]]` , is a list with two empty lists in it.  Since those lists are empty, you can't index into them.

Comment: what then when `i == 1` and `j == 1`? or any time `i > 0 or j >0 `?

Comment: @R Nar 's answer is better :)

Answer (score 0):

you can still use append but you have to initiate empty lists for each value first.

```
>>> NumberOfRows = 5
>>> [[] for __ in range(NumberOfRows)]
[[], [], [], [], []]
```

you can then call `append` on each item:

```
parameters = [[] for __ in range(NumberOfRows)]
for i in range(0,NumberOfRows,NumberOfColumns):
    for j in range(NumberOfColumns):
        k = i+j
        Parameters[i//NumberOfColumns].append(ParametersRaw[k])
```

Keep in mind the use of `range(0,NumberOfRows,NumberOfColumns):` which is the same as iterating your `i+=NumberOfColumns` until `i >= NumberOfRows`

I hope this works the way you want it to! I was unable to test it because I dont have any of your data so just comment if something is awry :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. Here is the last piece of code that cause me so much troubles but now working the way I wanted it:

```
fRawData = []
with open(fStagingFile2) as fStagingFile2FH:
    fRawData = [line.strip() for line in fStagingFile2FH.readlines()]   # This is to read each element from the file and chop off the end of line character

fNumberOfColumns = 7
fNumberOfRows = len(fRawData)/fNumberOfColumns

fRowID = 0
fParameters = []
for fRowID in range(0, len(fRawData), fNumberOfColumns):
    fParameters.append(fRawData[fRowID:fRowID+fNumberOfColumns])    # This is to convert 1D array to 2D

# and down below section is an example of how to read each element of the list
# and how to update it if I need so.
fRowID = 0
fColumnID = 0
for fRowID in range(fNumberOfRows):
    for fColumnID in range(fNumberOfColumns):
        if fColumnID == 0:
            fParameters[fRowID][fColumnID] = "XXXX"
        Message2Log("fParameters[" + str(fRowID) + "][" + str(fColumnID) + "] = " + str(fParameters[fRowID][fColumnID]))
```

CU

Answer (score 0):

If the size of parameter list is a multiple of numCols, then you can do it simply in few lines of code by using numpy.

```
import numpy as np
parameters = np.loadtxt("./filename.txt", unpack=True, dtype=str)
numCols = 7
numRows = len(parameters) / numCols
parameters = np.reshape(parameters, (numRows, numCols))
```